# Sum of conditional probabilities = Marginal probability?

Tags: probability, marginal-distribution

Is the following true?:
$P(X=j) = \sum_i P(X=j\mid Y=i)$

Thanks!

Comment: no it is not correct. just think of the case when the rhs is made of ones...

Comment: $$\begin{align} \Pr(X=j) & = \sum_i \Pr(X=j\ \&\ Y=i) \\ {} \\ & = \sum_i \Pr(X=j\mid Y=i)\cdot \Pr(Y=i). \end{align} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is No. The longer answer is presented below.

Here is an important, related statement that is true.

*For an exhaustive, mutually exclusive set of events B<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>,B<sub>3</sub>,...,B<sub>n</sub> (also called a partition) the Law of Total Probability holds:*
**P(A)=P(A,B<sub>1</sub>)+P(A,B<sub>2</sub>)+P(A,B<sub>3</sub>)+...+P(A,B<sub>n</sub>)**

Example:

- P(show is cancelled)=P(show is cancelled, it rains)+P(show is cancelled, it doesn't rain)
- P(an eventful day)=P(an eventful day, Monday)+P(an eventful day, Tuesday)+P(an eventful day, Wednesday)+P(an eventful day, Thursday)+P(an eventful day, Friday)+P(an eventful day, Saturday)+P(an eventful day, Sunday)

Because P(A,B<sub>i</sub>)=P(A|B<sub>i</sub>)*P(B<sub>i</sub>), the above Law of Total Probability can be rewritten as:

**P(A)=P(A|B<sub>1</sub>)*P(B<sub>1</sub>)+P(A|B<sub>2</sub>)*P(B<sub>2</sub>)+P(A|B<sub>3</sub>)*P(B<sub>3</sub>)+...+P(A|B<sub>n</sub>)*P(B<sub>n</sub>)**

In order for your statement to be true, each P(B<sub>i</sub>) must equal 1, but because B<sub>1</sub>,B<sub>2</sub>,B<sub>3</sub>,...,B<sub>n</sub> is a partition (exhaustive, mutually exclusive set)  it must be true that P(B<sub>1</sub>)+P(B<sub>2</sub>)+P(B<sub>3</sub>)+...+P(B<sub>n</sub>)=1, hence your statement must be false.

Comment: Please be cautious about providing full answers to self-study questions. Our policy is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).